# Why does my webpage freeze up?

Tags: jquery, load, freeze

I am loading a part of my site using jQuery's load function.
Everything works great, except for the fact that ever since I added the load function, my page freezes for 3-4 seconds during the loading.
I have been unable to find out what is causing this exactly... Any ideas?
My webpage can be found [here](http://www.funcampuses.com/rate/alabama-state-university).

Thanks!

Comment: I get a 404 error in console and also the freeze. Are you doing a synchronous load using a bad ajax request? There are a lot of js files in your website. Can you tell us which one has the load statement and the line number?

Comment: Could you show us the code you're using for the load function here, please?

Comment: sorry about that. no more 404. i am loading the content in the main page (html), using this code: $("#rate").load('/wizard/false #rating-wizard', function(data) {......}

Comment: I was just testing the page, but now I only get a 502 Bad Gateway when I try to load it.

Answer (score 0):

There might be other issues but the first thing I noticed in FireBug is you have a script error:

jQuery is not defined:
jQuery(this).css('marginLeft', -width/2);

This seems to be coming from selectToUISlider.JQuery.js

I would start by fixing this and see if you still hang. Might be unrelated but hard to tell while there are existing script errors.

Comment: how did you see this error? when i run the page i get no error in my firebug console..

Answer (score 0):

The reason your web page is "freezing" is because you are doing lots and lots of control initialization and some of it is slow.

On my computer it will eventually finish.

You could put in hidden timers to find out exactly where in the slowest parts are.

Also, looking chrome debugger I can see this request http://www.funcampuses.com/wizard/false it taking a very long time.

Comment: i know, but there is no avoiding this unfortunately - i have a lot of controls.. how do i do the this hidden timers business?

Comment: Really odd.  I too am seeing that URL taking all the time to load but simply calling [http://www.funcampuses.com/wizard/false](http://www.funcampuses.com/wizard/false) directly, it just pops right up.  @Aviv:  Can't you just remove this one thing and retest the page?

Comment: yeah its really odd. i could, but i need to content in it. its about 7kb, and when i put it directly inside the html and dont use load, the page takes a long time to load...

Comment: okay i've narrowed it down and its the SelectToUISlider call that hangs my webpage. why do these calls disable the scrolling on the webpage? this makes it literally impossible.. how can i circumvent this?

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I was calling a custom function for calculating the width of an invisible item. I was doing that for every label (average of ~10) in each slider (~40).
Obviously, this was very bad!